# Voting to migrate proposal

Tags: discussion, suggestion

I know it is still very early days, but as some of you know, someone has eventually taken that next step to propose a [stack for woocommerce](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce) questions.

As we all know, we get bombarded with a lot of woocommerce related questions on a daily basis. At this stage we just vote to close these questions.

My proposal is, since we can vote to migrate questions to either meta, SO, or webmasters, why don't we replace webmasters with woocommerce and then we can migrate good quality woocommerce questions to the appropriate stack (bad ones can still be closed and deleted on WPSE, we should not migrate crap).

We get webmaster related questions very seldom, maybe one a month, so we are actually wasting that migration spot. I think this will be a perfect opportunity to update our vote-to-migrate section so that it can be used for something useful

Comment: Is there a limit of how many destination sites you're allowed to have then? (you can't just add it as a fourth option.)  Also, I usually flag the Woocommerce questions as off-topic (*unless* someone has already left a comment saying they're off-topic) – is that the correct course of action or does it actually create more work?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the limit when it comes to vote-to-migrate sites, but it seems to be three. I know close vote reasons are limited to five as you have already seen :-). You should still flag off topic questions even if you suspect that someone has already flagged it. There is a gold badge for 500 successful flags raised. Once you hit 3K and get close voting privilidges, you can only tally successful flags with answers. So, flag flag flag. Remember, really poor questions can be downvoted as well, this helps in getting them deleted :-)

Comment: Maybe it would be a good start to promote the WooCommerce proposal from Area51 on our sidebar?

Comment: @Sven new proposals get advertized on all SE sites, but not frequent enough though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think migrating anything to an Area51 proposal is intended or technically possible, if that's what you are suggesting?.. Questions can't even be *answered* there.

Comment: I don't mean now :-), the site is still in the proposal phase on area 51 as you've stated, but I cannot see it not reaching beta at least. I just think this is something that we can start thinking about and maybe discuss so that we know exactly where we stand once the woo stack hits beta or any other stage which makes migration possible.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I don't know, I  think it's still a ways off from beta unfortunately. It got the initial push from the Community Ads topic but has since petered off... *If* it does hit beta then I completely agree about migrating woo questions . I've only seen 1 migration to Webmsaters since I hit 3k

Comment: @Howdy_McGee lets hope this happens fast :-). I think we might need to revisit this issue a bit later again as it does seem that I might have raised this to early :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Well I think it just needs one more push to get there, if somebody with enough pull could blog about it or the WooCommerce team could get behind it ( though I'm sure they're invested in the community support forums they made ) it could go through.

Comment: I am not sure migration to even beta would be approved, but indeed it's not even at that point. Woo team was made aware of it, they won't be getting behind it (their community area sadly is dead and discontinued now btw).

Comment: @Rarst ya, that is sad to hear that the woo team will not be getting behind the stack, so we might be sitting with this crappy issue indefinitely. O well, lets see what the future holds. Thanks for your input, appreciated :-)